# binding response string to object in ionic 3 using php and angular 5

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic 3 and I can retrieve data in response _body as string format but i can't able to bind key and values.

Here **list.ts** file

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
    /**
     * Generated class for the ListCustomerPage page.
     *
     * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
     * Ionic pages and navigation.
     */
    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-list-customer',
      templateUrl: 'list-customer.html',
    })
    export class ListCustomerPage {
      data:any = {};
      items:any = {};
      public res_data: any ='';
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http) {
      this.http = http;
      this.res_data= this.navParams.get('res_data');
      }
    ionViewDidLoad() {
    var link='http://localhost/CustomerRegistration/src/php/list.php?id='+this.res_data;
    this.http.get(link).subscribe(
      data =>{  
       this.items=data._body;
      });
    }
```

}

In console output:

```
Response {_body: "[{"customer_id":"440","customer_name":"test","cust…ated_at":"2018-08-17 07:55:07","deleted_at":"0"}]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
```

In list.html page
i get error key value "customer_name" undefine.

```
<h3>customer name</h3><b>{{items.customer_name }}</b>
```

how to use response data in list.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per response data is in `JSON` format you need to parse `JSON` data like below.

```
this.items = JSON.parse(data);
```

or in your case, your data is in one step inner with key-value "body".

So use like this :

```
let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
this.items = data("_body");
```

this will help you to get data in an array format.